# What does "fully supported" mean in context of Radeon Opensource Video Driver?

Tags: unity, radeon, 3d

**UPDATE:**

*This is not a request for support of my specific issue.  Details of that issue are here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/364326/how-to-recover-from-bad-upgrade-to-13-04-unity-very-slow .  I have "solved" that issue, for the time being anyway, by loading alternative lighter weight desktops.

This question was opened specifically to question the meaning of the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver .*

**END OF UPDATE**

There it is, in Black and White:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

> Fully Supported All these Radeon(HD) cards and derivatives have good
>   3D acceleration support. This is not an exhaustive list: 
>   ...
>   RV610/RV630                 Radeon HD 2400/2600/2700/4200/4225/4250

Yet in my case (the HD2400) this proves to be manifestly untrue, at least if "Fully Supported" means sufficient to run Unity in Ubuntu 13.04.

It runs all the applications I can launch under Unity, but Unity itself is unbearably slow.  It's quite striking really.  Click on the "Dash" - go get a cup of coffee.  Type a key in the Unity search box, wait five seconds for it to appear.  Type Alt-tab and wait five seconds for the screen to finish painting.  None of these issues appear outside of Unity components.  As you all know, there are complaints about slow performance all over the Internet about Unity.

Shouldn't this page somehow address this issue?  Especially if "fully supported" doesn't mean sufficiently to run the default modern Ubuntu release.

What does "fully supported" mean?

Comment: Well, the HD6650M is not the HD2400.  I didn't say support was bad with this driver for ALL cards listed, just that it was bad for mine, which was also listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully supported means exactly what you think it does.

But in your case there is clearly a regression. You should be filing this as a bug on [Launchpad.net](http://www.launchpad.net) so that developers are made aware of the issue.

Comment: ok.  Maybe they might even fix it?

Comment: @stevecoh1 That's less certain. Updates for it will come through kernel updates. The fixes might be backported but as I say, it's not certain.

Comment: sorry, I've been over to launchpad, logged in, can search bugs but am not allowed to enter one, anywhere that I can see.  What am I missing?

Comment: disregard comment above.  Figured out how to open bug report and did so.